# Activating the application gives the error "The Server is not Operational"

Tags: installation, smartassembly

Good morning,

I am trying to move an installation of SmartAssembly 6.8 onto a new developer machine.
It looks like it has installed without any issues, it starts ok and I get the dialogue with the Activate and continue buttons.  The machine I am installing SmartAssembly on doesn't have an internet connection, so I have been looking at the instructions here https://documentation.red-gate.com/sa6/getting-started/licensing/activating

If I click the Activate button to enter the serial number I get the following in a dialog box:

```
The server is not operational.
```

I have the option to send / save the error report, but that won't save either.

If I click continue and then try to activate from inside the app I get the same error message as above.  If I click the debug button on the form with the error message I get a little more information:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in SmartAssembly.exe
Additional information: The server is not operational.
```

Specs of the machine I am installing on are as follows:

```
OS: Windows 10 (64bit)
Memory: 4Gb
Disk Space: 50Gb free.

Apps:
    Visual Studio 2013
    MSSQL 2014
    .NET Framework 4.5.x and 4.6.1
```

I have also tried installing as a normal user and with administrator proveleges, but I get the same error.

I am clearly missing something obvious, so any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case I cured it by installing the latest update for that version, that seems to have done the trick.